# Mobile application web-based using Laravel

Tags: php, cordova, laravel, laravel-4, hybrid-mobile-app

Is it possible to make a web-based mobile application using a big project made in Laravel?
Do I need to start it from scratch in Cordova?
Please let me know how, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Laravel project only as an API to get and deliver data from and to the application.

If you have based your Laravel project on API, then this should be as easy as integrating with the web application. Otherwise, you'll have to build an API especially for the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel as your API backend and use the Cordova/Ionic or the native libraries to consume your API from the front-end.

Basically, have all your apps (mobile and web) use the same REST API, however you choose to program them. This will make your life easier and give you loose coupling.